# TIKZ drawing vector field

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector

How can i draw a vector field like this?[image]

Comment: In the meantime have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34004/quiver-scale-in-pgfplots-unit-scaling

Comment: Look for  **Quiver Plot**

Comment: In addition to @Dr.ManuelKuehner's link I'd suggest [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326042/3d-vector-fields-in-asymptote) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328086/121799).

Comment: This doesn't look like a vector field : you have curved arrows in your picture. Is this supposed to represent a flow of a vector field ? In any case you should precise your question, I think.

Comment: @Kpym It can be a vector field on some revolution surface. I agree that OP should precise his question (add more information about it)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I know this question has Ti*k*Z in the title. Nevertheless I'd like to present an asymptote solution since IMHO this does a much better job on real 3D graphics. Compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=AsyVF}
import graph3;
import three;
import solids;

size(6cm,8cm);
settings.render = 4;
currentprojection = perspective((9,4,4), up=Z,autoadjust=true);//,autoadjust=true
currentlight=(2,15,5);

// coordinate axes 
draw(-Z -- 2X-Z,L=Label("$x$",position=EndPoint));
draw(-Z -- 3Y-Z,L=Label("$y$", position=EndPoint));
draw(-Z -- 2Z,L=Label("$z$", position=EndPoint));

for (int irun=1; irun<=20; irun+=1)
{
real myx = sin(irun*2*pi/20);
real myy = -0.5;
real myz = cos(irun*2*pi/20);
draw(myx*X+myy*Y+myz*Z -- myx*X+myy*Y+myz*Z+(0.8+0.3*sin(irun*2*pi/10))*Y, arrow=Arrow3(), p=linewidth(0.5pt),light=currentlight);
//draw(shift(myx*X+myy*Y+myz*Z)*scale3(0.05)*unitsphere,lightgray,light=currentlight);
}

for (int irun=1; irun<=20; irun+=1)
{
real myx = sin(irun*2*pi/20);
real myy = 0.8;
real myz = cos(irun*2*pi/20);
draw(myx*X+myy*Y+myz*Z -- 1.2*myx*X+myy*Y+1.2*myz*Z+1.1*Y, arrow=Arrow3(), p=linewidth(0.5pt),light=currentlight);
//draw(shift(myx*X+myy*Y+myz*Z)*scale3(0.05)*unitsphere,lightgray,light=currentlight);
}

\end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]